# Hedetniemi's conjecture for 4-colorable graphs

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I am stuck on a passage from the [Wikipedia article concerning the Hedetniemi's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedetniemi%27s_conjecture#Known_cases):

> The next case has been proved long after the conjecture's statement, by El-Zahar & Sauer (1985): if the product G × H is 3-colorable, then one of G or H must also be 3-colorable. **In particular, the conjecture is true whenever G or H is 4-colorable (since then the inequality χ(G × H) ≤ min {χ(G), χ(H)} can only be strict when G × H is 3-colorable).**

Could someone explain me the argument in parentheses (must be really simple, but I don't see)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conjecture says (or rather said) that $G\times H$ can’t be coloured with fewer colours than can be achieved by lifting a colouring from $G$ or $H$. The preceding sentence in your quote says that it was proved that there’s no counterexample to this where $G$ and $H$ require more than $3$ colours (so all colourings lifted from $G$ or $H$ have more than $3$ colours) but $G\times H$ only requires $3$ colours. If $G$ or $H$ is $4$-colourable, then $\min\{\chi(G),\chi(H)\}\le4$ so the inequality $\chi(G\times H)\le\min\{\chi(G),\chi(H)\}$ can only be strict if $\chi(G\times H)\lt\min\{\chi(G),\chi(H)\}\le4$, that is, if $G\times H$ is $3$-colourable – but that’s precisely the kind of counterexample that the preceding sentence excludes.

Comment: It's a little bit clearer now, but I'm still confused. Instead of *If $G$ or $H$ is 4-colourable, then...*, shouldn't we write "If $G$ or $H$ is 4-**chromatic**"? We can have a graph $G$ that is 4-colourable (take a path, which is $2$-**chromatic**, and therefore $4$-colourable), and $\chi(G \times H) < 4$!

Comment: @Greg82: No, I think it's correct as it is. Indeed in your case $\chi(G\times H)\lt4$, but that doesn't make the inequality strict (i.e. it doesn't yield a counterexample to the conjecture). We have (assuming that $H$ has an edge) $\chi(G\times H)=\chi(G)=\min\{\chi(G),\chi(H)\}=2$ and thus equality and not strict inequality.